# Inno setup compiler: different type description for different languages

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I am trying to compile installer using "Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.3 (a)". I already included 2 different languages (using default .isl for specific language), but not I can not figure out how to change "Description" field of every type I have (i.e. "full", "compact" and "custom") differently for each language, but keep any other functionality, i.e. "Name" of type should stay the same.
My code now look like this:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "sl"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Slovenian.isl"

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"; Languages: en 
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"; Languages: en
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Languages: en; Flags: iscustom
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dont use the languages parameter of the `[Types]` section, unless you want some installer type to apply only to a specific language or language set.

To provide translations to the displayed type names, use the [`[CustomMessages]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_custommessagessection.htm) section, like this:

```
[CustomMessages]
en.TypeFullDesc=Create a &desktop icon
es.TypeFullDesc=Crear ícono en el &escritorio
sl.TypeFullDesc=The way you say create desktop icon in Slovenian

[Tasks]
Name: "full"; Description: {cm:TypeFullDesc};
```

The prefix in the CustomMessages section is used to identify to which language the entry applies.

Comment: Jachguate, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.